# Airtable right-click context menu overlap with browser context menu

Tags: airtable

When I right-click on a cell in the Airtable, the context menu should appear.

[image: Airtable context menu]

In some location of the table, however, the Airtable context menu overlaps with the web browser's context menu. Can I see both menus?

[image: Airtable context menu hidden by browser context menu]

P.S. I found that this problem does not occur in the Chrome browser because the web-browser context menu does not appear on the Airtable website. This problem occurs when I am using the Whale browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem of the Whale browser, rather than AirTable.
You may better to contact AirTable technical support or discuss at the AirTable community forum.

https://community.airtable.com/